# Greasemonkey Script Not Working on One Site

Tags: greasemonkey

I have Greasemonkey scripts working on several sites, but can't get one working on TitanTV. I don't see my log statement in the console.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        titantv
// @namespace   http://default
// @include     https://www.titantv.com/*
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==

console.log("Hello World");
```

Comment: Works for me...

Comment: Thanks. It works now after I deleted and re-created.